# Trouble subsetting data.frame from CRAN_package_db() based on colnames

Tags: r

I'm having problems subsetting a `data.frame` from `tools::CRAN_package_db()` by name:

```
apkgs <- tools::CRAN_package_db()
apkgs[1, 65] # character vector of length one with an MD5sum

# But these don't work:
apkgs[1, "MD5sum"] # NA
apkgs[1, names(apkgs)[65]] # NA

## But these work, even though they're very similar?
mtcars[1, "mpg"]
mtcars[1, names(mtcars)[1]]
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because two columns have the same name (14 and 65).

But you can use instead:

```
apkgs[1, which(names(apkgs) == "MD5sum")]
```

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. Seems like R should give a warning at least, though. Thanks!